# Java What does String input = " "; do?

Tags: java

I have seen some code with lines such as ..

```
String userChoice = " ";
userChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("User Input");
```

Could someone explain to me what this does? and how can I do this for an integer?

Comment: To see what it does, why not just run it? Or debug it with an IDE?

Comment: I did run it but I don't know what the purpose of it is because aren't you setting the user input to userChoice anyway with the second line? So, what's the purpose of the first line.

Comment: You're right that the first line is not needed if you declare the variable in the second line. `String userChoice = JOptionPane...`

Comment: The first assignment is redundant. You could change it to just `String userChoice;` and it would make no difference at all.

Comment: Okay thanks, my teacher used this and It was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

It assigns a string containing a space to `userChoice`.

The space and pre-declaration seem to be useless since it's assigned again in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

`String userChoice = " ";` declares the string-variable `userChoice` and assigns the temporary value of `" "` to it so that it is not an empty string.

Often times you cannot simply declare the variable at the same time as you will assign the value to it, because the variable might get out of scope - for example:

```
while(b) {
    if(a) {
        String userChoice = scanner.nextLine();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print(userChoice); //this will not work
```

The last line of code will not work, since `userChoice` is declared inside the while-loop and is not accessible outside of it. Instead, you would have to write something like this:

```
String userChoice;
while(b) {
    if(a) {
        userChoice = scanner.nextLine();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print(userChoice);
```

The reason behind assigning the value of `" "` to it is so that you do not get this compilation-error:

> variable userChoice might not have been initialized

An example of such a program can be the following:

```
String userChoice;
while(b) {
    if(a) {
        userChoice = userChoice + scanner.next(); //this will give you the error
    }
}
```

Since `userChoice` has no value, `userChoice + scanner.next()` doesn't mean anything and you get the error. By giving it the value of `" "` (or more commonly simply `""`), you avoid this issue.

Now in your case the above might be totally irrelevant and the code actually says something like:

```
String userChoice = " ";
userChoice = scanner.next();
```

instead of simply writing:

```
String userChoice = scanner.next();
```

and this is done only for educational purposes. There is no real difference, and you should always go with the simplest way of writing things.

Comment: While I agree with most of your post, I have to disagree with your last statement. Always go with the way that leads to the greatest long term maintainability and readability; ease of writing is just icing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I guess I used *"simplest"* poorly. I agree with you.